# difference between describe, it and def in ruby, rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am new to `rspec`. Going through tutorials, where I am stuck in beginning of it. 
When I was working with `WATIR`, `cucumber` framework I never saw `describe` and `it`.

So whats the difference? What to use when?

Answer (score 5):

Describe is used to explain what is being worked on. Typically you're going to describe a class and it's going to surround all of the `it` calls. `it` is the test case(s) that is/are executed within the `describe` block:

```
describe Foo do
  it "will return true" do
    expect(Foo.bar).to eq(true)
  end

  it "will return false" do
    expect(Foo.baz).to eq(false)
  end
end

# When run, rspec output is:
Foo
  will return true
  will return false
```

In the above case, the `it` method is describing how `bar` and `baz` will function on the `Foo` class. [A good read is the rspec documentation on this.](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it)

Comment: `it` is like methods inside a `class` we have in `java`. We can also reuse it in other methods using dot operator, like  `Foo.will return true`. Please quote an example if I am not doing correct way. And where does `def` comes in picture.

Comment: @paul `def` is how methods are defined in Ruby. Since you're not sure what `def` does, I'd suggest going through some learning material like: http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ it will give you the basics you need for Ruby programming.

Comment: Ok. And how to use `it` in other `it`. Would it work the way I wrote in previously comment.

Comment: The internal workings of `it` are quite complicated. Comparing it to `def` is not going to be very helpful until you've read the RSpec documentation, and some materials on Ruby.